# Bigram function using python

Tags: python, list, count

I want to count the number of occurrences of all bigrams (pair of adjacent words) in a file using python. Here, I am dealing with very large files, so I am looking for an efficient way. I tried using count method with regex "\w+\s\w+" on file contents, but it did not prove to be efficient.

Given a list of lists containing terms, return the most frequent
    bigrams. The return value should be a list of tuples in the form (bigram,
    count), in descending order, limited to the top n bigrams. In the example
    below, there are two documents provided; the top two bigrams are 'b c' (3
    occurrences) and 'a b' (2 occurrences).
This is what i've tried, but it lists count for all bigrams..

```
from itertools import tee, islice
def find_top_bigrams(terms,n):
    tlst = terms
    while True:
        a, b = tee(tlst)
        l = tuple(islice(a, n))
        if len(l) == n:
          yield l
          next(b)
          tlst = b
        else:
          break


find_top_bigrams([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']], 2)
>>[('b c', 3), ('a b', 2)]
```

I want the find_top_bigrams function to list atmost two output occurrences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data fits in memory, `collections.Counter` is your friend.

```
import collections

def list_to_bigrams(somelist):
    it = iter(somelist)
    old = next(it, None)
    for new in it:
        yield old, new
        old = new

def find_top_bigrams(n, *manylists):
    c = collections.Counter()
    for somelist in manylists:
        c.update(list_to_bigrams(somelist))
    return c.most_common(n)
```

If the data are too huge to fit in memory, then you'll have to work on disk -- much slower, but, for tens of gigabytes or more, what else are you going to do?  There are a few usable strategies for such a "big data" situation -- all the way to sophisticated distributed approaches such as mapreduce, to a simple single-processor approach based on merging and sorting plain disk files.

If you can explain your operational parameters better, I can tell more about the appropriate strategy or strategies.  But it does seem from your example that "very large files" may not mean to you the same as it means to me (tens or hundreds of gigabytes are middling-size -- it takes terabytes to use the word "large", and more than that for "**very** large").

So with the code I present above, the call would be slightly different:

```
find_top_bigrams(2, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
[(('b', 'c'), 3), (('a', 'b'), 2)]
```

the number 2 first, so all the rest of the arguments can be one list each (rather than having to use a less elegant list of lists).  But it's trivial to switch args around of course if you have to -- just change the `def` statement to

```
def find_top_bigrams(manylists, n):
```

and you can use exactly the call syntax you give in the example, while the rest of the code I proposed above stays the same.

Added: peculiarly it seems the output is constrained to be strings rather than tuple -- trivial change (though a terrible waste of good CPU cycles), just change

```
yield old, new
```

to

```
yield old + ' ' + new
```

or other formatting operation of choice (but this is simplest).  With this trivial change, of course, the result becomes `[('b c', 3), ('a b', 2)]`.

Comment: can you display the output which your function gives please..i'm getting an error running your code.

Comment: oh thanks. Can you make the changes in your code so that the output is just the same as i've shown above in my example..

Comment: @Wolf, displayed.  I see (now that your Q has blessedly been edited to make it more readable:-) that you peculiarly want strings like `b c` rather than tuples like `('b', 'c')`, let me edit again to show how easy it is to do that.

Comment: @Wolf you even lost the space now?!  That space **is** still in your question's example -- you just removed it in the comment -- and its absence would cause a lot of confusion, how would you distinguish `car ten` from `cart en`?!  I'm going to assume your comment is just wrong.